# startsWith function doesn't seem to be working

Tags: typescript

Im making a discord bot and trying to add commands, but when i try to use the startsWith function nothing happens when the test message contains the provided char

```
client.on("messageCreate", msg => {

    if (msg.content.startsWith('!')) {
        msg.channel.send('test')
    }

})
```

Comment: You're message doesn't contain what you think then. `"!test".startsWith('!')` // true

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler i have done some digging and i found when i send a message the bot sees it as an empty string and gives a "DiscordAPIError[50006]: Cannot send an empty message" error

Comment: by the way, startsWith resturns true if the string starts with `'!'` not if the string contains `'!'`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I just needed to enable "MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT" in the discord developer portal and add the "MessageContent" intent to my bot indents

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).